# is a sentence used to introduce a step in a long essay considered fragment?

Tags: sentence-structure, writing

For example: an essay about steps to become a successful student

**Firstly, memorizing every day.** [then all the other supporting sentences]

**Secondly, having a good amount of sleep every day.** [then all the other supporting sentences]

is these considered sentence fragments?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a sentence fragment from a grammatical point-of-view, but fragments often serve as section titles or headings. Very brief phrases and even single words can serve as headings.

Improving memory

Getting enough sleep

Whether you can do this really depends on the nature of the text you're writing. A "long essay" is very vague.

Comment: so even if they serve as headings or introductory phrases, it is wrong to use them in a formal essay, right?

Comment: We don't usually divide a formal essay into sections with headings.